# How do I differentiate whether the change triggered is a file upload/update/trash from the change object provided by google API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We are using the push notifications provided by google Drive API. The change id is pushed to the service by google, and we use the GET Api to retrive the change object. Our requirement is to find from the change object whether it is a file upload/update or trash. We tried using created date, modified date and modification date to find the difference. But the modification date is not providing the time the change happened originally and there is a difference of 2 seconds sometimes.. Also, When a folder is shared to multiple users, for the same change, the modification date which each user receive is different from that of the other and the difference is in seconds.

Please suggest if there is a way to distinguish between file upload/update/trash from change object.

Also, provide inputs on why the modification date is different for each user, and different from file modified date.

NOTE: We cannot use watch for files as per our requirement as there are lot of files in the drive and we can watch only for changes in the entire drive.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/